# Python argparser default value is getting split by letters

Tags: python, argparse

I have the below code to get an option in python

```
    parser.add_argument("--node", dest="node_list", metavar="all|<NODE1>,<NODE2>,...",
                    action='append',
                    help="Name of worker nodes on which daemonset pods have to be deployed seperated by comma(,).")
```

If `--node` is not given, I want to set default value as `all`. 
When I give `default="all"`, and loop through the node_list argument, here is what I get

```
       print nodeList
          for x in nodeList:
              print x
              if "all" in x:
```

And the O/P shows

```
all
a
l
l
```

So "all" is split as 'a','l','l'. 
If I explicitly give --node="all" , during execution , it works fine.

Comment: It sounds like you want `default=["all"]`, but keep in mind that this will always include `"all"`.  Alternatively, use `default=[]`, and then check for an empty list after parsing, replacing it with `["all"]` if empty.

Comment: @TomKarzes
yes ! I missed to try this way of execution.

Comment: During development use `print(args)` so you have a clear idea of what the parser produces - here whether it is a list or string.